# ReplayKit using WebRTC stops working after going to background repeatedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, replaykit

I'm using WebRTC to create a peer to peer connection for sharing screen and audio. I'm capturing the screen using ReplayKit, which generates `CMSampleBufferRef`; using that I can create `RTCVideoFrame`.

To get the `CMSampleBufferRef` I'm using:

```
[[RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder] startCaptureWithHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef  _Nonnull sampleBuffer, RPSampleBufferType bufferType, NSError * _Nullable error)
```

Up until this point, everything works perfectly.

The problem arises when I start sending the app to background and come back several times; then ReplayKit stops calling his capture handler.
This only happens if I send the `CMSampleBufferRef` to WebRTC, so it's clear that the ReplayKit issue is related to WebRTC. If I delete this line from the code, the issue doesn't happen (clearly WebRTC wouldn't work, though).

`[self->source capturer:self->capturer didCaptureVideoFrame:videoFrame];`

The only way I can get it to work again is to restart the device. Even killing the app and restarting doesn't work.

This is how I create `RTCVideoTrack` in my view controller:

```
- (RTCVideoTrack *)createLocalVideoTrack {

   self->source = [_factory videoSource];

   self->capturer = [[RTCVideoCapturer alloc] initWithDelegate:self->source];

   [self->source adaptOutputFormatToWidth:441 height:736 fps:15];

   return [_factory videoTrackWithSource:self->source trackId:@"ARDAMSv0"];
}
```

Here is how I convert the `CMSampleBufferRef` to `RTCVideoFrame` and send to WebRTC:

```
- (void)didCaptureSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer {

  if (CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer) != 1 || !CMSampleBufferIsValid(sampleBuffer) ||
    !CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)) {
    return;
  }

  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
  if (pixelBuffer == nil) {
    return;
  }

  RTCCVPixelBuffer *rtcPixelBuffer = [[RTCCVPixelBuffer alloc] initWithPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
  int64_t timeStampNs =
  CMTimeGetSeconds(CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)) * NSEC_PER_SEC;
  RTCVideoFrame *videoFrame = [[RTCVideoFrame alloc] initWithBuffer:rtcPixelBuffer rotation:RTCVideoRotation_0 timeStampNs:timeStampNs];

  [self->source capturer:self->capturer didCaptureVideoFrame:videoFrame];
}
```

Comment: This kind of issue is coming to me as well, Due to some reasons the Replay kit stops giving Video Buffers in capture handler (audio buffers are being received). The problem goes away once I restart the device.